# How to check if the file in the url exists or not

Tags: bash

I'm trying to check if a file in the url exists or not using `wget`, but the result it is giving is not as expected.

It is giving the result as `Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.`

The command I'm using is:

```
cd $path

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    touch laber.txt
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo $key >> laber.txt
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            wget -S --spider $url/laber.txt 2>&1 | grep -q 'HTTP/1.0 200 OK'
            if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                echo OK;
            else
                rm -r laber.txt
                echo FAIL;
            fi
        else
            echo 'test';
        fi
    else
      echo '3';
    fi
else
    echo '4';
fi
```

Comment: @Martin I'm expecting either zero or non zero as the result

Comment: Would you please take care on indenting the code??

Comment: Yes, `wget` normally behaves as you expect it to behave. It returns 0 if file exists or 8 if it does not. After the Spider mode banner `Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.` it should print the results of the actual request.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov But its not printing anything after that..

Comment: You're missing a `fi` in your code.

Comment: I've that in my script...

Comment: Perhaps you've got a buggy wget. Here is how it works on my system http://pastebin.ca/3605110

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to do it. Idea is to `grep` on the header output from `wget` on the requested URL and get the return code of the operation as such.

`grep` with `-q` will operate in silent mode i.e. will not output search string into `stdout` in case it is found.

A fancy one-liner could do the trick

```
#!/bin/bash

wget -S --spider $1 2>&1 | grep -q 'HTTP/1.0 200 OK' && echo SUCCESS || echo FAIL
```

***Confirmation:-***

```
$ ./script.sh www.go3463tgogle.com
FAIL
$ ./script.sh www.google.com
SUCCESS
```

**Traditional way:-**

```
#!/bin/bash

wget -S --spider $1 2>&1 | grep -q 'HTTP/1.0 200 OK'

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo OK
else
    echo FAIL
fi
```

***Confirmation:-***

```
$ ./script.sh www.go3463tgogle.com
FAIL
$ ./script.sh www.google.com
OK
```

You can use any actual `url` with the script to adopt for your case.

Comment: I've updated the code, can you please look into the code

Comment: Why do you have to check return codes of `echo`, `touch`? You can remove those checks and have only for `wget`. Also please improve the formatting of the script

Comment: Your script has bunch of unused variables `$key` `$url` are accessed without having a value. If you are ever feeling doubtful of the script, copy paste your script in https://www.shellcheck.net/ fix the errors

Comment: I'm passing $key and $url from php code to script. What I'm trying to do is I've a url sample.com/book.txt, if that particular file exist in that url, then it should return OK, else return FAIL... Any idea on how to do this??