# Checking if AWS S3 presigned link exists using wget --spider

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, wget

I've read several threads on SO about checking whether a URL exists or not in bash, e.g. [#37345831](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37345831/how-to-check-if-the-file-in-the-url-exists-or-not), and the recommended solution was to use `wget` with `--spider`. However, the `--spider` option appears to fail when used with AWS S3 presigned URLs.

Calling:

```
wget -S --spider "${URL}" 2>&1
```

Results in:

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
  HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
  x-amz-request-id: [REF]
  x-amz-id-2: [REF]
  Content-Type: application/xml
  Date: [DATE]
Server: AmazonS3
Remote file does not exist -- broken link!!!
```

Whereas the following returns as expected, `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`, for the same input URL:

```
wget -S "${URL}" -O /dev/stdout | head
```

The version of `wget` I'm running is:

```
GNU Wget 1.20.3 built on linux-gnu.
```

Any clue as to what's going on?

Comment: You might consider pulling out the [expiration time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46865679/amazon-s3-how-to-check-if-presigned-url-is-expired) from the URL and seeing if it's in the past.  This can be done without trying to pull down the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any clue as to what's going on?

There exist few [HTTP request methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) also known as HTTP verbs, for this case 2 of them are relevant

- GET
- HEAD

when not instructed otherwise `wget` does make first of them, when `--spider` option is used second one is used, to which server should respond with just headers (no body).

> AWS S3 presigned link

According to [Signing and authenticating REST requests - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/RESTAuthentication.html) one of step of preparing is as follows

```
StringToSign = HTTP-Verb + "\n" +
    Content-MD5 + "\n" +
    Content-Type + "\n" +
    Date + "\n" +
    CanonicalizedAmzHeaders +
    CanonicalizedResource;
```

therefore we might conclude that *AWS S3 presigned link* will be working with exactly 1 of HTTP verbs. One you have is for `GET`. Consult whoever crafted that link to furnish you with *AWS S3 presigned link* made for `HEAD` if you wish to use `--spider` successfully.

Comment: Thank you, apparently `--spider` does use `HEAD` instead of `GET`.